# Jinja range raises TemplateSyntaxError in Django view

Tags: python, django, range, jinja2

In a django jinja2 tempate with the code

```
{% for i in range(10) %}
    foo {{ i }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

a `TemplateSyntaxError` is raised with the error message

> Could not parse the remainder: '(10)' from 'range(10)'

What do I need to do in order to loop over a [range](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#range) in a jinja2 template.

I found a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls) in the django documentation explaining that

> Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

but I don't think that this applies to the range function.

Comment: You are not using Jinja2, you are using the Django template language. And why would this not apply to the range function?

Comment: It _seems_ that it's trying to parse the template as a Django template rather than a jinja2 template. That link to the Django docs is about Django templates, not jinja2 ones. What is your TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That seems to be exactly thie issue and I posted it as the answer, since this is the way Q/A sites work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is not using Jinja2, but the Django template language. There is no range function in the Django template language.